# Pythonic way to store rewards of states

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task connected with reinforcement learning. The state of my environment is described with the class below:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple

@dataclass
class LearningState:
    pre_cross_densities: Tuple[int]
    global_aggregated_densities: Tuple[int]
    phase_no: int
    phase_duration: int
```

I need the following behaviour (*):

```
state_1 =          LearningState(pre_cross_densities=(0, 4, 5), global_aggregated_densities=(2, 4, 5), phase_no=2, phase_duration=1)
different_state =  LearningState(pre_cross_densities=(0, 4, 5), global_aggregated_densities=(2, 4, 8), phase_no=2, phase_duration=1)
state_1_also =     LearningState(pre_cross_densities=(0, 4, 5), global_aggregated_densities=(2, 4, 5), phase_no=2, phase_duration=1)
myDic = {state_1: [2], different_state: [7]}
myDic[state_1_also].append(6)
print(myDic[state_1]) # prints [2, 6]
```

So the dictionary needs to see `state_1` and `state_1_also` as the same key. Also objects cannot be keys without a __hashable_ method implementation. To overcome these two problems I have created the following decorator.

```
def hashable(*args):
    def wrapper(cls):
        setattr(cls, '__hash__', eval('__hash__'))
        setattr(cls, '__eq__', eval('__eq__'))
        return cls
    return wrapper


def __hash__(self):
    all_properties = [prop for prop in self.hash_keys if not prop.startswith('__')]
    values = tuple([getattr(self, prop) for prop in all_properties])
    return hash(values)


def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()
```

Now I can write my class with the decorator and hash_keys properties as follows:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple
from services.hashable_decorator import hashable


@hashable()
@dataclass
class LearningState:
    pre_cross_densities: Tuple[int]
    global_aggregated_densities: Tuple[int]
    phase_no: int
    phase_duration: int
    hash_keys = ['pre_cross_densities', 'global_aggregated_densities', 'phase_no', 'phase_duration']
```

Code provides a (*) behaviour, but I feel like this is a sculpture. There will be a lot of data and I am also afraid about the performance couse there is a lot of immutable data.

Comment: If your state is immutable, you can use `@dataclass(eq=True, Frozen=True)`, then Python makes a hash function for you. If your class is mutable, you shouldn't use it as the key in a dict